# Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.guava:guava' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (18.0) and test app (16.0.1) differ

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-guava

I am getting below error,

```
  Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.guava:guava' in project ':app'.
  Resolved versions for app (18.0) and test app (16.0.1) differ
```

after adding the below line..

```
compile 'com.mobgen.halo.android:halo-plugin:2.0.0'
```

to dependencies
in build.gradle file

```
below is the snapshot of build.gradle file
```

[image]

i tried adding below 2 approaches in build.gradle file, but didnt work

1.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
}
```

2.

```
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava:guava'
    }
```

Comment: guys i dont know who is down voting and for what reason :S if possible try to help.. it will help others as well..

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

1. You're looking at the wrong thing. `Guava` is not a dependency of `Espresso`. It's a dependency of `testng`.
2. Although I might not be entirely correct saying that you're excluding guava in a wrong way, but the following scheme will work for sure:

```
androidTestCompile ("org.testng:testng:6.9.6"){
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module:'guava'
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue as him and the solution above does not solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: @guest176969 look at the `dependencies` gradle task dump (you might need to dump it to a file because of the amount of text). Maybe it's included in something else as well.